# Start Qt application from bash script and crontab

Tags: linux, bash, qt, ubuntu, cron

I have important Qt application (bot to execute repetitive tasks), but often is problem with it and the application closes. Solution I was found in bash script. Script checks is process exsits - when application was automatically closed, runs it again. When I run my script in terminal - everything is ok, Qt application starts again.
Problem is in crontab. Script executes in time, but not fire my application. Is it possible to do this in crontab?

Bash script (with chmod 777):

```
if [MY_CONDITION_TO_CHECK_PROCESS] 
then /PATH_TO_MY_APP 
else echo "Is OK" 
fi
```

Crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /PATH_TO_MY_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Run `env -i sh -c '/PATH_TO_MYSCRIPT'` in your terminal to more closely simulate the environment that cron uses to run your script. You'll probably have to tell the Qt app where to show its window by setting the `DISPLAY` variable.

Comment: Now I received "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display" message

Comment: Set DISPLAY to your display!

Comment: I set display... Internet says `env DISPLAY=:0 [gui_appname]`. I tried `*/1 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /PATH_TO_MY_APP` but it also doesn't work. Obviously this command in terminal runs correctly.
I also tried solution, which I found here [link](https://www.bricolage.io/ubuntu-tutorial-how-to-launch-an-gui-from-cron-i/) but also doesn't work.

Comment: Ok... I added task to root crontab and I wonder why it doesn't work.
Command `export DISPLAY=:0 && /PATH` solved problem.